Can I reformat this poker hand history data using code or a script?
The poker hands that I play are auto recorded by the software that I use into a certain format, which looks about like this:
Hand #2511720-7 - 2024-04-13 20:04:23
Game: NL Hold'em (2000+0) - Blinds 10/20
Site: APT Live Server
Table: Saturday Shootout - No Late Registration - Table 2
Seat 1: mrmet (2000) - sitting out
Seat 2: HMB1321 (2130)
Seat 3: mastertech (1930)
Seat 4: gege (1860)
Seat 5: jjskps (1970) - sitting out
Seat 6: GreenFriend (2050)
Seat 7: tewtadle (2080)
Seat 8: SL3vinKelve1 (1980) - sitting out
Seat 9: grgoad (2000) - sitting out
tewtadle has the dealer button
SL3vinKelve1 posts small blind 10
grgoad posts big blind 20
** Hole Cards ** [9 players]
Dealt to tewtadle [8d 2h]
mrmet folds
HMB1321 calls 20
mastertech folds
gege folds
jjskps folds
GreenFriend folds
tewtadle calls 20
SL3vinKelve1 folds
grgoad folds
** Flop ** [Jc 2s Qh]
HMB1321 checks
tewtadle checks
** Turn ** [Th]
HMB1321 checks
tewtadle checks
** River ** [6d]
HMB1321 checks
tewtadle checks
** Pot Show Down ** [Jc 2s Qh Th 6d]
HMB1321 shows [8c 5c] (High Card Queen +JT86)
tewtadle shows [8d 2h] (a Pair of Deuces +QJT)
tewtadle wins Pot (70) with a Pair

In order to analyse this data using a program that I have (Hand2Note) I need to reformat this data to make it identical to the example below, different cards, amounts, players, dates, times, etc. but the same formatting. I tried playing around with the Notepad++ find and replace function but gave up quite quickly due to the complexity. I am now thinking about paying someone to come up with a program of some sort that can do this reformatting for me (assuming it is possible and feasible). The question now of course is, is this feasible and if yes then how difficult is it? Could I do this myself with some time investment or is it better to pay someone to come up with a way to reformat this data quickly and easily? If of interest, the blocks of data being reformatted contain around 100-200 hands each hand has an entry about as long as the example listed above. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you very much :).
PokerStars Hand #174088855475:  Hold'em No Limit (50/100) - 2017/08/08 23:16:30 MSK [2017/08/08 16:16:30 ET]
Table 'Euphemia II' 6-max (Play Money) Seat #3 is the button
Seat 1: adevlupec (53368 in chips) 
Seat 2: Dette32 (10845 in chips) 
Seat 3: Drug08 (9686 in chips) 
Seat 4: FluffyStutt (11326 in chips) 
FluffyStutt: posts small blind 50
adevlupec: posts big blind 100
*** HOLE CARDS ***
Dealt to FluffyStutt [2h Ks]
FluffyStutt said, "nh"
Dette32: calls 100
Drug08: calls 100
FluffyStutt: folds 
adevlupec: checks 
*** FLOP *** [8h 7s 8d]
adevlupec: checks 
Dette32: checks 
Drug08: checks 
*** TURN *** [8h 7s 8d] [Th]
adevlupec: checks 
Dette32: checks 
Drug08: checks 
*** RIVER *** [8h 7s 8d Th] [2c]
adevlupec: checks 
Dette32: checks 
Drug08: checks 
*** SHOW DOWN ***
adevlupec: shows [Qs Ts] (two pair, Tens and Eights)
Dette32: mucks hand 
Drug08: mucks hand 
adevlupec collected 332 from pot
*** SUMMARY ***
Total pot 350 | Rake 18 
Board [8h 7s 8d Th 2c]
Seat 1: adevlupec (big blind) showed [Qs Ts] and won (332) with two pair, Tens and Eights
Seat 2: Dette32 mucked [5s Kc]
Seat 3: Drug08 (button) mucked [4d 6h]
Seat 4: FluffyStutt (small blind) folded before Flop

